# DOJO: Unable to display portlet correctly

Tags: dojo, portlet

I want to display basic portlet on mozilla browser in dojo 1.7, but the following is displaying data as simple text without actually creating any portlet using dojo API. Could anyone please tell me what wrong I'm doing?

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../lib/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
<style type = "text/css">
@import "../lib/dojox/widget/Portlet/Portlet.css"</style>
<script src = "../lib/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config = "async: true, parseOnLoad:true" >
dojo.require("..lib/dojox/widget/Portlet");
dojo.require("..lib/dijit/dijit");
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.widget.Portlet" title="A Simple Portlet">
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.widget.PortletSettings">
    This is a simple setting widget.
    Put Whatever you like in here
</div>
<div style="height: 100px;">
The contents of the portlet go in here.
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `dojox.widget.Portlet` source code. It's not rewritten to [AMD](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.6/async-modules) format and therefore you are not able to resolve dependencies. Even the test `dojox/widget/tests/test_Portlet.html` does not work.

To workaround this switch the loader into sync mode defining `async: false` or completely omit the definition as in Dojo 1.7 the synchronous mode is default.

There is also another unresolved dependency, which I resolved by explicitly requiring AMD module `dijit._Container` before requiring `dojox.widget.Portlet`:

```
dojo.require("dijit._Container");
dojo.require("dojox.widget.Portlet");
```

See the working example at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/MWnYZ/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm still unable to display portlet correctly on browser if try to call your code  as HTML file. I get exception on module "dijit.Container". Could you please tell me what's the reason of this?

Comment: Didn't you just mistype something, e.g. `dijit._Container`? I just copy-pasted the jsFiddle code into a file and it works the same way as in the jsFiddle in all browsers. What kind of exception are you getting?

Comment: In chrome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dijit//_Container.js. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: It's the security constrain. You have to run the code via HTTP server like Apache or so, you are running it as local file (i.e. `file://` instead of `http://`).